# ECS services taking more than 10 minutes to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS to deploy my services, I've 2 services but after starting the ECS instance from my ASG, `ecs-agent` docker container comes up immediately but both of my service containers takes more than 10 minutes to come up.

I am using `t2.medium` instance and both these services are very small and doesn't do any checks at startup times.

Let me know if I need to provide any other information. Note I've checked in events section and even there is no information until instance is started.

Comment: Can you just try on a bigger instance and see whether there is any difference to rule out the infra bits

Comment: Another reason could be, Your image size might be large

Comment: @nischaygoyal, earlier i was using t2.small it was not that bas AFAIK and my image size is very small(~300-400 MB
)

Comment: Can you pull image before hand and then run `docker run IMAGE` and all other options and post the logs